# JSON.net stuck at DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got a JSON as following

```
{"name1":20,"name2":22}
```

My aim is to save it in a List of People so that it can be used afterwards, so I first wrote the class People:

```
class People
    {
        public String name{get;set;}
        public long age{get;set;}
    }
```

I wrote as long as to prevent [this deserializing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813350/json-net-deserializeobjectlistt-not-returning-list-nor-giving-error).

Then I wrote the following code:

```
String json= new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);
List<People> people= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<People>>(json);
```

But it gets stuck at processing this last line (no errors / no crash ..), why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your Json should look more like this if you want to deserialize to List

[{"name":"Name1","age":20},{"name":"Name2","age":22}]

Comment: I find it very frustrating that the deserialise method does not throw some kind of exception. I do a lot of work like this in background tasks and it feel like a silent failure every time I come across this.